# Stop text moving when thead is clicked

Tags: jquery, html

Ok so i've set up this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PvXLw/) to demonstrate my issue. I have a table that when I click the thead the rows hide and unhide when clicked, which works great. The issue I'm seeing though is that the header text 'moves' when clicked. I dont understand the reason  for this and cant seem to figure out how to fix.

```
<table id="table-results" class="table table-hover table-condensed table-results">
    <thead>
        <tr class="header">
            <th colspan="2">LATEST RESULTS</th>
            <th colspan="1"><span><i id="chevron" class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></span>

            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Date</td>
            <td>Home Team</td>
            <td>Score</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Date</td>
            <td>Home Team</td>
            <td>Score</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Date</td>
            <td>Home Team</td>
            <td>Score</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS here:

```
$('.header').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('table').children('tbody').toggle();
    if ($('#chevron').hasClass("fa-chevron-left")) {
        $('#chevron').toggleClass('fa-chevron-left fa-chevron-down');
    } else {
        $('#chevron').toggleClass('fa-chevron-down fa-chevron-left');
    }
});
```

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Try setting a width to your `th`.

Comment: <th colspan="2" width="40%">

Comment: thanks both, this did work, but setting the table-layout also did as below. Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `table-layout: fixed;` styling in the table, and it would work great! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because the default layout of a `<table>` is `auto` and it will adjust itself to it's content, and when you hide that content the columns will be adjusted to what remains.

Try setting a width to your `<th>` elements and they should stick.

Comment: thanks, this works, but I happened to choose the table-layout: fixed; option

Comment: `table-layout: fixed` is probably the better solution in your case, so no argument here :)